# How to set RecordInterceptor to ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Kafka 2.2.7, I have configured `@EnableKafka` with `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` and using `@KafkaListener` to consume messages, everything is working as expected.

I want to add a `RecordInterceptor` to log all the consumed messages but finding it difficult to configure it. The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#receiving-messages) states that RecordInterceptor can be set on a container, however I'm not sure how to obtain an instance of the container.

> > > Starting with version 2.2.7, you can add a RecordInterceptor to the listener container; it will be invoked before calling the listener allowing inspection or modification of the record.

```
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Bytes> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Bytes> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(createConsumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(consumerCount);
        return factory;
    }
```

I've looked through the Spring documentation but haven't found a solution, it seems to be a simple thing but perhaps I've missed something.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method [setRecordInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/config/AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.html#setRecordInterceptor-org.springframework.kafka.listener.RecordInterceptor-) since `2.2.7`

```
factory.setRecordInterceptor(new RecordInterceptor);
```

And another information [RecordInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#receiving-messages) will not work for batch listener

> Starting with version 2.2.7, you can add a RecordInterceptor to the listener container; it will be invoked before calling the listener allowing inspection or modification of the record. If the interceptor returns null, the listener is not called. **The interceptor is not invoked when the listener is a batch listener.**

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I knew I was missing something silly but it's even sillier!
I was on 2.2.3 when I checked whether factory has this method, obviously it wasn't there. Forgot to check again after upgrading.

Comment: Does setRecordInterceptor act like ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG=1 in kafka consumer config?